# Restart MySQL server without disrupting users

Tags: mysql, lamp, restart

What are some generally accepted strategies for restarting a MySQL server on a busy website without interrupting current users?  I am using a LAMP setup.  I don't mind taking down the site for a time if need be, but if certain user activities are interrupted I could wind up with corrupted data.  I do have the ability to bring up a second server if that helps in the transition.  I need a solution that results in no corrupted data / data loss.

I suspect this could be a common problem without an easy solution, but not sure what the best approach would be.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks, Brian

Comment: more of a question for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

Any solution for high availability depends on redundancy.

The most popular strategy today is to [run *two* MySQL servers](http://capttofu.livejournal.com/1752.html).  Configure the two servers to replicate bidirectionally.  This comes with its own challenges; you must manage your applications carefully to write to only one server at a time, to avoid creating update conflicts.  When you need to restart one MySQL server, [switch your apps to use the other MySQL server](http://mysql-mmm.org).

Even with this configuration, you can't make the switchover without interrupting connections, even if the interruption is brief.

Another solution is [MySQL Cluster](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster.html), in which both MySQL Servers and storage are redundant, but this is also complex to set up and manage, requires high-end hardware resources, and shards your data in ways that make it hard to optimize for general SQL queries.